# How to get Combobox.SelectedItem Return string value of what is selected instead of Service Reference Class?

Tags: c#, wcf, combobox, pivotviewer

I currently have the following code for a button. The message box shows `SilverlightApplication2.ServiceReference2.Employee` instead of the text string selected by the user. The combobox items are being populated by a WCF service. As a result I am unable to pass it to the Async call. How do I get the string of what user selected?

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    object selectedItem = comobo1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.ToString());
    var proxy = new Service1Client();
    proxy.GetAllEmployeesCompleted += proxy_GetAllEmployeesCompleted;
    proxy.GetAllEmployeesAsync(selectedItem.ToString());
}
```

My Service Reference looks like

public class dropdown
    {

```
    [OperationContract]
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> GetAllBrands()
    {   

        var empstwo = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yoyo"].ToString();
        using (var con = new OdbcConnection(connect))

        {  
            //now you can try
            //wait. To accept a param from main page, u need to create a method to accept that param first.
            //I think you should put this in service1.svc.cs

            string query = "Select distinct(brand) FROM pivottable";
            var cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {


                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var emp = new Employee();

                    emp.ComboData = dr.GetStringOrNull(0);

                    empstwo.Add(emp);

                }


            }



        }

        return empstwo;
    }

}
```

and this is the employee class. In this string ComboData holds the list of brands which populates my dropdown list

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageURI { get; set; }
    public string ComboData { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the selecteditem to the type of object you are binding.Something like this,

```
var selected = (Employee)comobo1.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(selected.ComboData.ToString());
```

Comment: var selectedItem = (ServiceReference2.Employee)comobo1.SelectedItem; The messagebox still returns SilverlightApplication2.ServiceReference2.Employee

Comment: <ComboBox x:Name="comobo1" DisplayMemberPath="ComboData" SelectedIndex="3"  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboData}"  Width="150"  Margin="-25,-25,222,0">
                
            </ComboBox>

Comment: @RohitAcharya Not this part , the place where you fil the data. you have posted the xaml

Comment: The message box still returns SilverlightApplication2.ServiceReference2.Employee instead of the selected string I used var selectedItem = (ServiceReference2.Employee)comobo1.SelectedItem;

Comment: I have a seperate service reference for combobox, does it make a difference? hence I have (ServiceReference2.Employee)

Comment: @RohitAcharya you need to get the combobodata from the selected item. check the modified answer

Comment: Nope I dint, I dont have enough reputation to upvote, Will increase my points and click up surely mate

Comment: you can mark as an answer, there is a tick mark on the left just click it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Text` property.

```
string selectedText = comobo1.Text;
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Gets or sets **the text** of the currently **selected item**.

Comment: It says System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox does not contain definition for Text

Comment: @RohitAcharya, isn't it a silverlight app ? and it does have [Text property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Why? care to explain the reason?

Comment: @YuliamChandra Text and SelectedItem will return the same,OP wants to cast the selecteditem

Comment: @Sajeetharan, you sure 100% it will return the same ?? and I simply provide the answer of the actual problem

Comment: ya i dint downvote your answer, according to my knowledge i felt it wil not work. Also i guess its a wpf/silverlight application which he dint mention

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code to get Value,Text of an Combobox SelectedItem Programatically

ComboboxItem cmb = new ComboboxItem();

cmb = (ComboboxItem)cmb_designation.SelectedItem;

staffreg.Designation=int.Parse(cmb.Value.ToString());